# Inksoft API 2.0 - How can I set ArtId on a ShoppingCartItem

Tags: rest

I am attempting to add a ShoppingCartItem object with an ArtId to my ShoppingCart object using Inksoft's API 2.0.

I've been attempting to use SetCart but after a successful post the ArtId is always returned as null.  I've used ArtIds returned from the SaveArt method as well as ArtIds from Inksoft's clipart.

I have the same issue with the Notes field, which I was hoping to use as a workaround.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.